# selectively clear file contents perl

Tags: perl

I have a input.txt file in this format:

```
DP_00296.1: 1-2, 72- 82
DP_00575.1: 63 -68, 206  - 208
DP_00389.1: 486-, 493-499, 529-  544
```

I want to clear some formats as:
i) clear the space(s) that might present before or after a "-"
ii) if a "-" is not followed by any number, delete that "-"

For the above input.txt, I want final output.txt be like:

```
DP_00296.1: 1-2, 72-82
DP_00575.1: 63-68, 206-208
DP_00389.1: 486, 493-499, 529-544
```

Please suggest a perl code (preferably an one liner) that can do the job in one go instead of substituting in regex for two times?

ps: My apologies for my approach @ zdim and @ Jim Garrison.. actually i'm looking for the regex that i'm comfortable with. Here what I hv tried:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
local $/=undef;
open(FILE, "input.txt") || die ("Error\n");
$string = <FILE>;

$string =~ s/\s//g;
print "$string";
```

Thanks

Comment: _"Please suggest a perl code (preferably an one liner) that can do the job "_ -- Sorry, that's not the way StackOverflow works.  YOU are expected to attempt a solution.  If you encounter difficulties, post what you have written and explain what is not working.

Comment: _Please_, show us what you are doing.  It's all so different then.

Comment: @zdim.. I have edited my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On each line, capture the numbers and evaluate a simple condition in the replacement part

```
perl -pe 's/(\d+)\s*-\s*(\d*)/ $2 ? "$1-$2" : "$1" /xge'  input.txt
```

With `/e` modifier the replacement part is evaluated as code. See it [in perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators) and [in perlretut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Using-regular-expressions-in-Perl).

We need `*` quantifier in the second number for the match to *succeed* so that the replacement is carried out.  The problem specifies that only the second number may go missing, while it also allows a sole number to exist without a dash, thus the first number has `+`.

The `-p` sets up the loop over input, sets `$_` to the current line, and prints it after processing.

Comment: should it have to be modified to run in an windows machine?

Comment: @J.Carter Huh ... not sure.  There is nothing system-specific but I have never run a one-liner on Windows, so I can't tell.

Comment: ok.. i will check.. but in linux too.. it delete the third line character "486- ," and in output it gives only a ","

Comment: @J.Carter So ... ?  It should remove the comma?

Comment: it should print "486, "

Comment: @J.Carter Updated for that.  Now it strictly follows the problem specification where only the number _after_ `-` may be missing.  It also now handles the comma (removes it if the range gets removed)

Comment: @J.Carter  Removed the bit about the comma as it is not needed

Comment: uuuummmmmmmmm... but the output third line should be: "DP_00389.1: 486, 493-499, 529-544"

Comment: @J.Carter Corrected. I understood "_delete that -_" so that the whole range should be removed

Answer (score 2):

Trying to do it as a one liner is probably more trouble than it's worth. Parse it, clean it up, reassemble, and print it back out again.

Your basic line format is pretty simple:

```
key: value, value, value, ...
```

First, split the key from the values on a `:`.

```
my($key, $value) = split /:/, $line;
```

Then split the values up on commas.

```
my @values = split /,/, $value;
```

Now you can leisurely strip out whitespace from each value.

```
# This works because $_ in a for loop is an alias, not a copy
s/\s+//g for @values;
```

And assemble the line back together again.

```
say "$key: ".join(", ", @values);
```